# Speed up averaging of numerically solved differential equations

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, compile

I deals with a coupled system with non-linear differential equations of first order. I perform numerical solution with `NDSolve` and then use obtained solutions, `{f_1[t],...,f_N[t]}` to calculate time-averaged values, i.e,

```
r = NIntegrate[f_1[t], {t,0,T}] * 1/T
```

I would like to vary parameter of my system, say `g` and calculated time averages for each value of parameter. To do it, I use

```
averages_g = Table[ NDSolve[...], NIntegrate[...] ]
```

However, for relatively large number of equations performance of my code is awful. I know that it seems possible to use machine code compilation, see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/CodeCompilation.html). I try to use it and write down the function that  solves equations and calculates averages. I set

```
RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True
```

for my function and it seems that code works faster. **Is it possible to make something more in order to improve performance?**

Minimal working example is:

```
order = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {p, _Integer}, {T, _Real}, {g, _Real}}, Quiet[
    Block[{gr, A, M, freqs, synchfreq, equations, initial, 
       sol, \[Phi]}, {gr = 
        Graph[SortBy[
          Flatten[{Table[1 <-> 2 + i*p, {i, 0, n - 1}], 
            Table[2 + k + i*p <-> 3 + k + i*p, {i, 0, n - 1}, {k, 0, 
              p - 2}]}], Last], VertexLabels -> Automatic]; 
       A = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[gr]]; M = VertexCount[gr]; 
       freqs = VertexDegree[gr]; synchfreq = 2.*n*p/(n*p + 1.); 
       equations = 
        Table[\[Theta][i]'[t] == 
          freqs[[i]] + 
           g*Sum[A[[i, k]]*Sin[\[Theta][k][t] - \[Theta][i][t]], {k, 
              1, M}], {i, 1, M}]; 
       initial = 
        Table[\[Theta][i][0] == RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}], {i, 1, M}]; 
       sol = Flatten[
         NDSolve[{equations, initial}, 
          Table[\[Theta][i][t], {i, 1, M}], {t, 0, T}, 
          PrecisionGoal -> 10]]; \[Phi] = 
        Table[\[Theta][i][t] /. sol[[i]], {i, 1, M}]; 
       NIntegrate[
         Abs[Total@Exp[I*\[Phi] - I*synchfreq*t]/M], {t, 0, T}, 
         Method -> {"MonteCarlo", MaxPoints -> 20000}]/T}][[1]]], 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True];

   n = 5; p = 4;
   Rvalues =  Parallelize[order[n, p, 1000, #] & /@ Table[i, {i, 0, 3, 0.01}]]
```

Comment: It is impossible to improve performance or even understand your problem without code and working example.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have edited the question and provide the minimal working example

Comment: Did you solve your problem using answer by Roman?

Comment: @AlexTrounev , only one case. As you can see, I would like to choose random initial conditions for a given value of parameter. In Roman's answer, we assume that initial conditions are the same for every parameter value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can exclude integration by including additional equation in `equations`. Also we don't need to use `ParametricNDSolve` since there are random initial conditions. Actually we can reduce time for one order with the same option `PrecisionGoal -> 2`  (this is Automatic option for `Method -> "MonteCarlo"`). Initial code

```
Clear["Global`*"]

order = Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {p, _Integer}, {T, _Real}, {g, \
_Real}}, Quiet[
     Block[{gr, A, M, freqs, synchfreq, equations, initial, 
        sol, \[Phi]}, {gr = 
         Graph[SortBy[
           Flatten[{Table[1 <-> 2 + i*p, {i, 0, n - 1}], 
             Table[2 + k + i*p <-> 3 + k + i*p, {i, 0, n - 1}, {k, 0, 
               p - 2}]}], Last], VertexLabels -> Automatic];
        A = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[gr]]; M = VertexCount[gr];
        freqs = VertexDegree[gr]; synchfreq = 2.*n*p/(n*p + 1.);
        equations = 
         Table[\[Theta][i]'[t] == 
           freqs[[i]] + 
            g*Sum[A[[i, k]]*Sin[\[Theta][k][t] - \[Theta][i][t]], {k, 
               1, M}], {i, 1, M}];
        initial = 
         Table[\[Theta][i][0] == RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}], {i, 1, M}];
        sol = 
         Flatten[NDSolve[{equations, initial}, 
           Table[\[Theta][i][t], {i, 1, M}], {t, 0, T}, 
           PrecisionGoal -> 10]]; \[Phi] = 
         Table[\[Theta][i][t] /. sol[[i]], {i, 1, M}];
        NIntegrate[
          Abs[Total@Exp[I*\[Phi] - I*synchfreq*t]/M], {t, 0, T}, 
          Method -> "MonteCarlo", PrecisionGoal -> 2, 
          AccuracyGoal -> Infinity]/T}][[1]]] // Re, 
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, Parallelization -> True, 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"];
```

New code

```
ordern[n_, p_, T_, g_] := 
  Block[{gr, A, M, freqs, synchfreq, equations, initial, sol}, 
   gr = Graph[
     SortBy[Flatten[{Table[1 <-> 2 + i*p, {i, 0, n - 1}], 
        Table[2 + k + i*p <-> 3 + k + i*p, {i, 0, n - 1}, {k, 0, 
          p - 2}]}], Last], VertexLabels -> Automatic];
   A = Normal[AdjacencyMatrix[gr]]; M = VertexCount[gr];
   freqs = VertexDegree[gr]; synchfreq = 2.*n*p/(n*p + 1.);
   equations = 
    Join[{ave'[t] == 
       Abs[Sum[Exp[I*\[Theta][i][t] - I*synchfreq*t], {i, 1, M}]/M]}, 
     Table[\[Theta][i]'[t] == 
       freqs[[i]] + 
        g*Sum[A[[i, k]]*Sin[\[Theta][k][t] - \[Theta][i][t]], {k, 1, 
           M}], {i, 1, M}]];
   initial = 
    Join[{ave[0] == 0}, 
     Table[\[Theta][i][0] == RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}], {i, 1, M}]];
   sol = NDSolveValue[{equations, initial}, ave[T]/T, {t, 0, T}, 
     PrecisionGoal -> 2]; sol];
```

Test on v.12.2 for Windows 64-bit (4 kernels been used)

```
n = 5; p = 4;

    Rvalues = 
     Parallelize[order[n, p, 1000, #] & /@ Table[i, {i, 0, 3, 0.01}]] // 
      AbsoluteTiming
    (*18.3001*)
    n = 5; p = 4;
    Rvalues1 = 
     Parallelize[ordern[n, p, 1000, #] & /@ Table[i, {i, 0, 3, 0.01}]] // 
      AbsoluteTiming
    (*1.71137*)
```

Visualization (please, pay attention that we use random ic)

```
ListPlot[{Rvalues[[2]], Rvalues1[[2]]}]
```

[image: Figure 1]

Comment: Nice! It seems elegant and simple. To be honest, I do not know about the function `NDSolveValue`. Thanj you so much!

Comment: What `PrecisionGoal`? I have no intuition how case `PrecisionGoal->10` and  `PrecisionGoal->2` differ

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov For your code with option `Method -> "MonteCarlo"` for integration there are automatically used two options `PrecisionGoal->2, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity` (I put these options in the initial code just for clearance). Therefore option `PrecisionGoal->10` in `NDSolve` has no sense. If we try to use more precise  method like  `"GlobalAdaptive"`, then the time increases up to 100 s.

Comment: Thank you for clarifications!

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov You are welcome!

Answer (score 12):

It is often easier to use built-in functions instead of compiling and/or parallelizing. Here, a combination of [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html) and concurrent integration could work.

As an example, assume you are starting from a differential equation
$$
f''(t) + [a + b \cos(t)] f(t) = 0
$$
which depends on two parameters $(a,b)$. We can solve this equation numerically for specific initial conditions with

```
ParametricNDSolve[{f''[t] + (a + b Cos[t]) f[t] == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0},
                  f[t], {t, 0, 10},
                  {a, b}]
```

and evaluate the resulting interpolating [`ParametricFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricFunction.html) object for arbitrary parameters $a$ and $b$ (corresponding to your $g$ parameter). This is much more efficient than integrating the differential equation afresh for every new parameter set $(a,b)$.

To get the moving average $u(T)=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^T f(t)dt$, we can add an additional concurrent differential equation for the integral
$$
F(T)=\int_0^T f(t)dt
$$
which is $F(0)=0$ and $F'(t)=f(t)$, solved with

```
S = ParametricNDSolve[{f''[t] + (a + b Cos[t]) f[t] == 0, f[0] == 1, f'[0] == 0,
                       F'[t] == f[t], F[0] == 0},
                      F[t], {t, 0, 10},
                      {a, b}]
```

from which we can plot the running average $u(T)=F(T)/T$:

```
Plot[F[t][0.3, -0.8]/t /. S, {t, 0, 10}]
```

[image]

(here for example with $a=0.3$ and $b=-0.8$)

An alternative to using the cumulant $F(T)$ would be to find $u(T)$ directly from its differential equation
$$
u(t)+t u'(t)=f(t) \qquad \text{with $u(0)=f(0)$}
$$
which, unfortunately, does not work because Mathematica's numerical solver cannot deal with the non-essential singularity of this differential equation at $t=0$.

Comment: Thank you for beautiful book and thank you for the answer, it works perfectly

Comment: @Roman Could you extend your answer for the minimal working example with `F[0]=RandomReal[{0, 2*Pi}, M]`, and with `M=VertexCount[gr]`?